# Oracle | Compression Disadvantages and Advantages

Tags: oracle, compression, oracle12c, oracle19c

We have oracle 12c database. We will be migrating to 19c soon. Generally we follow rule to compress table(advanced OLTP compression) and keep indexes uncompressed. Now we are facing situation where depending upon number of columns we have some indexes with 800GB and its corresponding table is of 200GB(compressed)

Can someone help me with understanding of below-

1. Does tables compression have impact on query performance/table loading
2. Should we compress index? Will it impact performance of loading or querying?
3. If table is partitioned can we selectively compress local indexex partition by partition.

Are there any best practices or dos or donts  for Oracle compression?

Comment: This question is well suited for [https://dba.stackexchange.com/](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). May be posting there would get quicker response.

Comment: @learningloop: I disagree. From a given size (say a million rows), an expert database developer would certainly need to understand how table and index compression work to design a good and scalable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Re 1:

Table compression can have an impact on performance, mostly a positive one. However, it is nearly impossible to predict, as it depends on the data, and on the order the data is inserted into the table, the number of updates, etc.

I'd normally check firstly the potential compression ratio of a table, either with `dbms_compression.get_compression_ratio` or by simply creating a compressed and an uncompressed copy of the table (or a subset of the rows if too big).

Re 2:
Index compression eliminates leading values in multicolumn indexes, so the answer is the same as for 1.

Re 3:
Yes. According to the [partitioning guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-0C13E8A8-568B-4A60-8A46-F1120D193EFE.htm#VLDBG1111), you can use

```
CREATE INDEX i_cost1 ON costs_demo (prod_id) COMPRESS LOCAL (
    PARTITION costs_old, PARTITION costs_q1_2003, 
    PARTITION costs_q2_2003, PARTITION costs_recent NOCOMPRESS);
```